# handy script to reduce hardlink count?

Tags: linux, filesystems, nfs, hard-link, aws

I'm transitioning a large fileset from a filesystem with a high `_PC_LINK_MAX` (maximum number of hardlinks per inode) to a lower one.

In particular, I'm messing about with Amazon EFS, which has a maximum of 175, as stated [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/limits.html).

So I'd like to have the input be a set of files with link counts as high as 250 rejiggered, so that the inodes get split, so that  the max is 100 links each.

Is there a clever invocation of, say, `hardlink`  that can do this? Or perhaps an option to `rsync -aH` or maybe `cp -a` which can help?

...otherwise, some hackery is in order...

Comment: Maybe it would be enough to have a command (say cp or rsync) which give you nice error messages (a list of files, unable to create because of max links). Then after the first run you only copy/rsync  the failed files again.

Comment: Determining the problem fileset is easy via find -ls.  In my case it's a majority of the files.  I'm looking for a one-liner for what to do with the target set.

Comment: No, not just determining the problem fileset. I mean in best case the first `rsync -H` run would create many "max-175 files" and skip all further links. The next `rsync` run (with source file list) would create _new_ files and not link against existing target file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation is tricky. Imagine the maximum links is 5 and you have 12 files
`a01` to `a12` all hard-linked together. You need to split out `a01..a05` and `a06..a10` and `a11..a12`, where `a06` and `a07` etc are still hard-linked together, but not to `a01`.

Here's a bash script using `rsync` that runs on an example source directory (`src=/usr/libexec/git-core/`) on my system which has 110 hard-links. It simulates a maximum number of 50 links (`max`) in the destination directory `realdest` by the function `sim`. In a real case you would just ignore the *too many links* errors, and not use this function.

After the initial normal rsync (with errors), the list of missing files is created by using `rsync -ni`, extracting the filenames in function `calctodo` into `/tmp/todo`.

There is then a loop where we `rsync` the missing files, again ignoring *too many links* errors (which you would have if you had more than `2*175` links in the original directory). The successfully created files are hard-linked amongst themselves.
The new list of missing files is calculated. This is repeated until there are no more files.

```
src=/usr/libexec/git-core/
realdest=/tmp/realdest
#rm -fr "$realdest"
max=50
sim(){
    find ${1?} -links +$max |
    sed "1,${max}d" |
    xargs --no-run-if-empty rm
}
calctodo(){
    sed -n '/^hf/{ s/[^ ]* //; s/ =>.*//; p }' >/tmp/todo
}

rsync -aHR   "$src" "$realdest"; sim "$realdest"
rsync -niaHR "$src" "$realdest" | calctodo

while  [ -s /tmp/todo ]
do  mv /tmp/todo /tmp/todo.old
    rsync -aHR  --files-from=/tmp/todo.old / "$realdest"; sim "$realdest"
    rsync -niaHR --files-from=/tmp/todo.old / "$realdest" | calctodo
done
```

You may need to revise this if you have filenames with " => ", newlines and so on.

---

Note, you can find the maximum number of links supported by a filesystem by

```
getconf LINK_MAX /some/directory
```

Comment: Great, I agree that this strategy will work.

Comment: I simplified the code: you don't need an intermediate temporary destination directory.

Comment: The nice thing about this is that it can be run (error-free) on the source filesystem and then you can tar-snap in the reduced directory over a slower link.